# Alterar Css com javascript ao clicar

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tenho um círculo em css e metade dele fica escondida. Quando clica nele, quero que a parte escondida apareça. Ao clicar de volta, quero que ele volte a esconder.
Fiz o seguinte código javascript, o problema é: clico, aparece; clico, esconde; clico de novo e não acontece nada.  Quero que fique aparecendo/escondendo quantas vezes o usuário clicar.

```
$(".icone-btn").click(function() {
     $(".btn-contato").css("marginTop", "-170px");
        $(".icone-btn").click(function() {
        $(".btn-contato").css("marginTop", "-230px");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crie uma classe para manipular isso.

```
.margintop230 {
margin-top: -230px !important;
}
```

Deixe já no estilo do seu circulo o padrão de -170px;

```
.btn-contato {
margin-top: -170px;
}
```

No javascript você vai "alternar" a classe .margintop230 a cada click:

```
$('.icone-btn').click(function(){
     $('.btn-contato').toggleClass('margintop230');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Cada vez que você clica, está criando um novo *listener* de clique que determina a margem como  `-230px`. Resolva com um único manipulador de eventos. Uma das maneiras é alternando os valores da margem de acordo com o valor atual:

```
$(".icone-btn").click(function() {
     var atual = .$(".btn-contato").css("marginTop");
     var nova = atual === "-170px" ? "-230px" : "-170px";
     $(".btn-contato").css("marginTop", nova);
});
```